# Is this way of using indirect addressing correct?

Tags: c, pointers

I'm watching a college lecture about direct and indirect reference.

The professor just said that you can access a determined address by putting * and the address ahead of it. In  the example he gave `printf("%d", *7);` will print the value in the memory address 7. That doesn't happen to be true, at least it didn't work at all for me.

For example, I had a variable `num` at address `0x28cc48` or `2673736`. When I do `*b = &num`, I can access the variable's value with `printf("%d", *b);`, but If I try `printf("%d", *2673736);` or `printf("%d", *0x28cc48);` that won't work.

Here's the lecture, for those who want to check it: https://youtu.be/Rxvv9krECNw?t=8m45s

I don't know, I think his explanation is broken, but it may be that I'm missing the point, so I'm willing to know a bit more about this from the more experienced ones.

Comment: Tip: won't work = ?. Syntax error? UB? Logical error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using `*7` in your code, the compiler has no real idea of what you are trying to de-reference. If you, on the other hand, tell it `*(int*)7`, it knows it has to de-reference it as an int.

In general, location 7 in memory would not even be accessible and it is a bad practice to hardcode addresses into your code. In the case of microcontrollers or embedded systems however, it might be used however.

When you say `*b = &num`, it matters whether you are doing it at declaration time, or after it, since `int *b = &num;` is very different from `int *b; *b = &num;`. In fact, the first usage is the same as `int *b; b = &num;`.

Here's some code to clarify the scenario that you are probably trying to get to:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int num = 5;
    int *a = &num;
    int *b; b = &num;
    printf("num = %d, &num = 0x%x", num, &num);
    printf("a = 0x%x, *a = %d", a, *a);
    printf("b = 0x%x, *b = %d", b, *b);
    printf("*0xAAAAAAAA = %d", *(int*)0xAAAAAAAA); // Note: Replace 0xAAAAAAAA with whatever value you get for num from previous executions of this program
}
```

PS: It might be worth to take a look at Stanford's excellent resource on Pointers and Memory. http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/102/PointersAndMemory.pdf

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access memory at a fixed address (common for example when accessing registers on a microcontroller), use an expression like this:

```
int tmp = *((int*)0x01234567);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since a constant number does not really have a type, in order to use a constant number as an address, you have to tell the compiler the type of address by using a cast.

So if you have a particular memory address in low memory with certain types of constants you would need to specify the memory address with the cast in order for the compiler to know what type is the data at that memory location.

For instance you may have a set of unsigned shorts that are counters starting at a memory location of 8 with device names starting at a location of 0x700 so you could access them like so:

```
unsigned short iVal = *((unsigned short *) 8);  // get unsigned short value at address 8
unsigned short jVal = *((unsigned short *) 10);  // get unsigned short value at address 10
char  *iName = (char *) 0x700;    // get the address 0x700 into a char pointer
char  *jName = (char *) 0x710;    // get the address of 0x710 into a char pointer
```